# vscode debug code in node_modules directory

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a node_js project that includes some of our own node_js packages.  They are in an npm private repo and show up in node_modules as:

```
@company/package_name
```

We are trying to set breakpoints in this code and find they are never hit.

We thought there might be a default skipFile that excludes node_modules and added to our launch.json:

```
"skipFiles": ["!${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js"]
```

to no effect.

Any tips on how to enable debugging in the node_modules directory?

Comment: Have you found a way to do it ?

Comment: What happens if you step into a library call from your code?

Comment: @Nick I find when I try that, VSCode doesn't step into it, it still steps over it.

Answer (score 41):

I know it's an old question but if someone still manages to stumble upon this, you can use VS code to debug node_module files by first symlinking the node_module package with the main project and then telling VS code to use the symlink.

### Symlink node_module package

If you are going to be working in a node_module package, it's a good idea to symlink it so that the changes that you make from within your projects are simultaneously applied to the module's code as well and hence, when you are done editing the package, you can directly see the diff and commit it and instead of copy-pasting it from inside node_module and applying it manually.

1. To symlink a package inside node_module with your project, first clone the repo on your system.
2. Run `npm link` inside the directory.
3. Then go to your main project and then run `npm link package_name` to link it.

For example, if you wanted to link a package *sample-node-module* with a project *sample-project*, which uses *sample-node-module* as its dependency, you can do it in the following manner:

```
cd sample-node-module
npm link
cd sample-project
npm link sample-node-module
```

Be careful that you enter the folder name (and not the package name itself) of the cloned repo in the second `link` command. You don't have to provide the full path. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

### Telling VS Code to use symlinks while debugging

Once you are done with above, you can simply add this small config in your launch.json of VS Code to make it detect breakpoints inside node_modules:

```
{
"runtimeArgs": [
    "--preserve-symlinks"
]
}
```

Documentation about this can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_can-i-debug-if-im-using-symlinks)

Comment: Hey Chris, if this answer solves your problem, please upvote and mark the answer as 'Accepted answer'. Thanks :)

Comment: surely there must be a better way? I'm reading about `debug.javascript.autoAttachSmartPattern` .. havnt figured it out yet, but want to use the configurable way if possible rather than playing with symlinks

Comment: Hey @Flion thanks for your response and pointing the new method out! As you can see, this answer itself is more than 2 years old and at that time this is what worked for me. I looked at what you have suggested and seems like it might work but since I can't try out what you have suggested right now, if you can write another answer or even update this one to include that info would be great :)

Comment: It's not working please [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136755/cant-set-breakpoints-on-npm-linked-library)

Comment: I tried to see if this helps with my linked library but it's not working. Might be a path issue as well? Trying to make sense on what to set for the correct path in sourceMapPathOverrides for the linked module.

Comment: if you are using `yarn`, it's the same, just `yarn` instead of `npm`

Comment: same thing for pnpm... `pnpm link ...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with source maps. Try to add `node_modules/example-package` files to `resolveSourceMapLocations` in launch.json, where `example-package` is directory of module, in which you want to set breakpoint:

```
"resolveSourceMapLocations": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "node_modules/example-package/**/*.js",
]
```