# How to debug an NPM library package in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, redis

I have made a library in `Typescript` and will be using it in other `NodeJS` projects. I have included the source code in the `NPM` package, so when I install it in my projects where I consume this package, I get the source as well in the `node_modules` folder.

Now, while debugging my project, I want to be able to hit the breakpoints set in the library code inside `node_modules`. How can I do this?

Suppose I have my project that I am trying to debug at `root/my-project` and this project is using an NPM package named `@my-org/common` which is located at `root/my-org-common`. Since this library is installed in `my-project` using NPM, the code for `@my-org/common` is also included in `node_modules` at `root/my-project/node_modules`. How do I set up my VSCode so that breakpoints inside code at `root/my-project/node_modules` are hit?

Comment: If you want to debug the library, maybe just temporarily adjust the `main` property in package.json to point to `src` (or equivalent) instead of `dist`/`build`?

Comment: The project code I am talking about is an ExpressJS project which has routers and controllers and the library code has just data models, utils and service methods. I want to debug the library methods which are called through the service. Will changing the `main` in package.json work in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no tests for the library code or I would have debugged it using those tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution here: [vscode debug code in node_modules directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021083/vscode-debug-code-in-node-modules-directory)

Basically, you have to create a symlink which points to the code of the library and then instruct VSCode to use this symlink by putting this in `launch.json`:

```
{
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--preserve-symlinks"
    ]
}
```